# Inserting file to the download url sent by google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to insert a file to google drive through API.

I successfully posted the new file metadata to drive and received the JSON response contaning the download url.

In the next step I am trying to post the content of the file to the download url provided and as a result I am able to insert the file successfully but it's contents are not visible.

Can anyone please tell me exactly in which format should the file contents be posted?

Comment: Could you share the file publicly and post the link here so we can have a look at it? Also upload the same file using the Web UI and share it publicly as well so we can compare.

Comment: This is the link of one of the file i tried to upload. It is uploaded by one of my colleague. The link is "https://docs.google.com/document/d/173yWKvfT3E0qCHT3f5llW7iEe7gaycsU3IU1sAivzrE/edit"

Comment: This links works for me and is is a Google Document. Is that the file you are trying to upload to Drive using the API? How is the original file? Is it a Microsoft Word document?
Could you also try to share one of the File that you failed to upload so we can see what is wrong? (please use right click > Share from the Drive UI)

Comment: Let me explain you the entire flow. I am working on force.com and the entire authorization part including receiving the download url is done at force.com itself. For inserting the file I am sending request to a proxy that uses asp.net. It accepts my request and access token and from there sends the request to insert that file to google drive.

Comment: The file I am trying to upload is a Microsoft Word Document saved at force.com server. The above link that I gave you is one of the file we tried to upload to google drive through the api. I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: All right, so could you also show me one of the files that have not worked properly? You said: "as a result I am able to insert the file successfully but it's contents are not visible." Would it be possible for you to show me one file, created through the API and for which the "contents are not visible.". I'm  trying to see what you are experiencing and what is wrong with the file. Is there any content  uploaded to Drive? Is it just not converted to a Google Docs? etc...

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a file is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/insert#examples). Choose `Python` in the tabs selection and it should work.

If you want to update the file's content, you can have a look at the [drive.files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/update#examples) endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for answering Alain. Actually the link that you have given me makes use of sdk provided by google whereas I have to work with the API. Since I am working on force.com I cannot make use of any sdk's provided.

Comment: Which API are you using? Are you referring to the Documents List API? In this case, you should follow the instruction available [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_and_uploading_documents_and_files).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use endpoint **update** with the file id - endpoint **insert** is for new files (returns the id).